# How to test ssh port forwarding using netcat (nc)?

Tags: bash, ssh, windows-8.1, cygwin

I'm attempting to debug an issue with port forwarding, which is "Why can I not limit which port to connect to?"  This isn't the question here though. This question here is "Why won't nc send any data across a forwarded port?"

Starting simple on the local machine:

1. I've installed OpenSSH under Windows 8.1.  Easy.
2. Add the lines to the beginning of the sshd_config file:

   ```
   PermitTTY no
   MaxSessions 1
   ```
3. I start up the sshd using command `net start sshd`.
4. I start up a cygwin bash shell (also tried with git-bash) and type the command: `ssh -N -L 1234:localhost:5678 adrian@localhost`, and type in password.
5. I start up another cygwin bash shell and type in the command `nc -l 5678`.
6. I start up yet another cygwin bash shell and type in the command `nc -v localhost 1234`.

At this point, I would expect to see that the connection succeeded and now be able to type stuff in the 2nd cygwin bash shell and have it appear on the 1st.  However, what I do get is the message that the connection succeeded and then it drops me back to the bash prompt.  WHY?

### Examples

1. The succeeded message where it then booted me to the command line was:

   ```
   $ nc -v  localhost 1234
   Connection to localhost 1234 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

   $
   ```

   This also occurs if I don't have the `nc` listener running and attempt to connect over the forwarded port.
2. I can connect directly to the port and I get an error message, then a success message, and finally I can type in one shell and it'll show up in the other:

   ```
   $ nc -v  localhost 5678
   nc: connect to localhost port 5678 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
   Connection to localhost 5678 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
   ```

   This is consistent if I were to connect on a port that isn't forwarded and regardless if sshd is running.
3. Without the port forwarding, if I don't have the `nc` listener running and attempt to connect over the previously forwarded port, it fails:

   ```
   $ nc -v  localhost 1234
   nc: connect to localhost port 1234 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
   nc: connect to localhost port 1234 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
   ```

## EDIT

So, based on the answer, it would seem that the failure is that `nc -l 5678` will connect to incoming IP4 packets.  `nc localhost 5678` will first try sending IP6 packets and if that fails, try again with IP4 packets.  `sshd` communicates with `nc -l 5678` via whatever packet type it receives from `ssh`.  Since that is IP4 packets, it fails, closes the tunnel which then closes the `ssh` which will then close the `nc` sender before it retries to send out IP6 packets.

To fix, get the listener to only accept IP6 packets by using command `nc -6l 5678`, then everything works correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSH "port forwarding" is a bit different from the one performed by routers. Where a router forwards each IP packet individually and unaltered, SSH deals with generic signals such as "connection opened" and doesn't forward the actual TCP operations at all.

That is, SSH acts as a pipe between two completely independent TCP connections ("nc→ssh" and "sshd→nc-l"), unlike a router which carries the same connection from end to end.

So with SSH it is actually *your local system* which accepts the TCP handshake from `nc`, and the SSH client only becomes aware of this *after* it has already been accepted. Then the SSH client sends a "tunnel open" request to the server, which attempts to make a brand new TCP connection to the final destination. If it doesn't succeed, it sends a reply to your client that "tunnel open failed".

At this point, it is too late for your local system to inform `nc` of an error in the usual way – remember that it has already accepted the connection; it can immediately close it, but it cannot travel back in time and fully reject it.

(The 'refused' message you *do* see is related to `localhost` translating to both IPv4 127.0.0.1 and to IPv6 ::1 – nc tries to reach both, but the ssh client was told to only listen on one.)

> So, based on the answer, it would seem that the failure is that nc -l 5678 will connect to incoming IP4 packets. nc localhost 5678 will first try sending IP6 packets and if that fails, try again with IP4 packets. sshd communicates with nc -l 5678 via whatever packet type it receives from ssh. Since that is IP4 packets, it fails, closes the tunnel which then closes the ssh which will then close the nc sender before it retries to send out IP6 packets.

No. It's kinda like that, but – to repeat – **the actual IP packets never go across the tunnel at all.** There are two independent connections (maybe three if you count the actual SSH session) and the IP version attempted by the local `nc` client *can* be different from the IP version received by the remote `nc -l` listener.

More specifically, these are the two client-server pairs:

1. Local system: `nc localhost 5678` as the client ⇆ `ssh -L ...` as the listener;
2. Remote system: `sshd` as the client ⇆ `nc -l 5678` as the listener.

The first connection refusal shows up because *ssh -L* is not expecting the IP version that *nc localhost* was trying. This attempt does not reach the remote system (neither *sshd* nor *nc -l* are aware of it).

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear on this. The `nc -v localhost 1234` connects because it is connecting to the `ssh` forwarder.  But why does it close?

Comment: Because the server finds out that you don't have the nc listener running, and the `ssh` forwarder then closes the connection to indicate failure.

Comment: What are you defining as the server? `sshd`?  But the `nc` listener is running.

Comment: Oh, so what you are saying is that because my example 2 is showing that the nc listener will fail first and then succeed, that the sshd is saying that there is no connection here and closes the tunnel, which then propagates back to the other nc and then shuts down. And this is because it is trying an IP6 call before the IP4, which is the only one that will work.  Got it.

Comment: The "failing at first" bit has nothing to do with the sshd. It's misconfiguration on the client side and is a completely unrelated problem. Only nc's second connection attempt (the one which succeeds and immediately closes) actually goes through the tunnel.

Comment: Ok, so I'm starting to see this. So, your saying that `sshd` isn't aware of anything (*"neither sshd nor nc -l are aware of it"*) when `ssh` closes the connection with the `nc` client? This would indicate that the open connection to `sshd` failed to establish. Why does the connection fail between the `ssh` client and `sshd` server in the first place when the `nc` client is trying to establishing a IP6 connection and the `nc` server is only accepting a IP4 connection, but yet the connection succeeds if the `nc` server accepts a IP6 connection?  How can `sshd` not know anything is happening?

Comment: It would seem to me that `sshd` would have to at least attempt a connection to the `nc` server and fail, before the tunnel is collapsed.  And if that is the case, then the `nc` server would, at some level, know that a connection was attempted and reject it.

Comment: No. You're still confusing two completely separate connection attempts. When the `nc` client is trying to establish an IPv6 connection, this attempt _doesn't even reach the `ssh` client_, much less the server. (I think you're still imagining SSH tunnelling as if it worked at IP packet level and were the same as NAT port-forwarding...)

Comment: Then how do you explain that when I start up the `nc` server with the command `nc -l6 5678` and by way of the `ssh` tunnel, I can successfully communicate with it with the same original command `nc -v localhost 1234`?  The `nc` client is still doing the same thing as it did before, but now succeeds to connect and communicate whereas before it failed and dropped back to the command line. The only thing that has changed is the server side, so communication must be happening across the tunnel.

Comment: I guess you either lost interest in the question or don't have an answer?