# Linux ssh reverse tunnel connects without endpoint

Tags: linux, ssh-tunnel, reverse-tunnel

I am using ssh reverse tunnels (using AutoSSH) to allow incoming connections on certain ports on my Internet server, to be tunneled to Local Servers on my house LAN.

My problem is that the SSH accepts incoming connections on the external ports, even when there is no end-point; That is, the local Server is not running at all (but the PC is). Which should cause a local RESET from that PC.

Still, a TCP connection is established on that external port.
Worse, when during an existing tunnel connection, the local Server is shut down (either with a clean TCP shutdown, or even with a TCP-RESET) this is NOT forwarded back to the external client, and from this Client's perspective, the connection still exists.

Is there anything which can be done about this?
It is started from systemctl:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH Tunnel
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=1

[Service]
#PassEnvironment=AUTOSSH_POLL=30
PassEnvironment="AUTOSSH_DEBUG"
Type=forking
GuessMainPID=1
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process
User=nosh
ExecStart=/usr/lib/autossh/autossh -M 20000 -C -N -f -n -T \
     -R '*:1234:192.168.50.150:1234' \
     -R '*:1235:192.168.50.200:1235' \
     -R '*:1236:192.168.50.130:1236' \
     -R '*:1237:192.168.50.1:1237' \
     nosh@mydomain.com -p 2200 >> /dev/null 2>&1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Welcome. You should take a look at [ask] and take the [tour], if you have not done so already. Also take a look at [example].

Comment: "Still, a TCP connection is established on that external port." – See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1544027/432690) for some explanation. The most important fragment: "At this point, it is too late for your local system to inform `nc` of an error in the usual way – remember that it has already accepted the connection; it can immediately close it, but it cannot travel back in time and fully reject it."

Comment: Kamil, thanks. +1 . That explains a lot. Looks like I have to write a fast ping/pong keep-alive system for the clients/servers, to quickly cause a disconnect when either Client or Servers are missing or off-line. Thanks.